# My volume keeps reseting

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. 
I have very little knowledge of linux and ubuntu, just downloaded few days ago, and my volume for some reason keep reseting to either 74% or mute every few seconds. I volume down and then few second after its randomly back at 74% or muting itself.
I've been googling around for the past 4 hours and i've never been more frustrated with a tech issue before.
Only thing I noticed is that whenever it happens, `pulseaudio -v` returns the following:

```
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Synced.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Successfully enabled deferred volume.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Hardware volume ranges from -179.00 dB to 0.00 dB.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Fixing base volume to 0.00 dB
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Using hardware volume control. Hardware dB scale supported.
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-sink.c: Using hardware mute control.
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c: Changed port of sink 0 "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo" to analog-output-headphones
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Restoring volume for sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Restoring mute state for sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Storing volume/mute for device+port sink:alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo:analog-output-headphones.
```

Let me know if more details are required. And if you have anyhting to add that can get me closer to solving it, please do, I am completely clueless and frustrated.